# Constraints on BsplinesComp

Tags: openmdao

I am using BsplinesComp for a sample problem. 
The objective is to maximize the area under the line. 
My problem arises when I want to set a constraint for one of the values in the output array that bspline gives. So a value such that the spline goes through that no matter what configuration it is in. 
I tried this in two ways and  I have uploaded the codes. They are both very badly coded so i think there is a neater way to do so. Links to codes:
https://gist.github.com/stackoverflow38/5eae1e86c5802a4df91becdf580d28c5

1- Using an extra explicit component in which the middle array value is imposed to be a selected value

2- Tried to use an execcomp but I get an error. Target shapes do not match. 
I vaguely remember reading such a question but could not find it.

Overall I am trying to set a constraint for either the first, middle or last value of the bspline and some range that it should be in. 
Similar to the plots here

[image]

Comment: do you mean that you want all values of the bspline to be within those ranges? or that you want to constraint a specific value on the split to be within those ranges, but other values along the spline can violate the bounds?

Comment: I would not mind learning how to do both but my initial concern is to constraint a specific value and merge with the rest smoothly. One more drawback of the codes I have uploaded  (apart from being un-neat) the enforcement of the first value is causing a discontinuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think you want to know the best way to do this, and the best way is to not use any extra components at all. You can directly constrain a single point in the output of the BsplinesComp by using the "indices" argument in the `add_constraint` call.  Here, I constrain the first point in the spline to lie on the interval [-1, 1].

```
model.add_constraint('interp.h', lower=-1, upper=1, indices=[0])
```

Running the model gives me a shape that looks more like one of the ones you included.

Just for reference, for the errors you got with 1 and 2:

1. Not sure what is wrong here, but maybe the version you uploaded isn't the latest. You never used the AeraComp in a constraint, so it didn't do anything.
2. The exception was due to a size mismatch in connecting the vector output of the Bsplines comp to a scaler expression. You can do this by specifying the "src_indices", giving it a list of which indices in the array to connect to the target. `model.connect('interp.h', 'execcomp.x', src_indices=[0])`

Comment: Indeed ''indices'' was the one i am looking for. I really appreciate the quick responses for my rudimentary questions. Even though I have read the features before and did skim the addconstraint again before posting i was not thorough enough. Thanks.